# setError() sobrepondo o ActionBar

Tags: android, android-layout

Eu tenho uma tela que o usuário altera seus dados, e como validação eu uso o **setError()** para especificar qual elemento está com o valor incorreto. Mas estou com um problema quando tenho scroll na tela, a mensagem do **setError()** simplesmente sobrepõe o ActionBar. Eu pesquisei algumas formas de resolver esse problema, mas nenhuma é eficiente.

Print da situação

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**UPDATE**

Segue o layout que estou usando.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ECEDEE"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="9dp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/fundocomsombra"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"  >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textCadastroDescricao"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextGray"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="@string/cadastro_descricao" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="6dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/fundocomsombra"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"  >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textCadastroPlaca"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/size12"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextGrayForte"
            android:text="@string/cadastro_placa"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editCadastroPlaca"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:maxLength="8"
            android:hint="Digite sua placa" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btProsseguir"
            android:paddingTop="11dp"
            android:paddingBottom="11dp"
            android:background="@layout/fundoverdepressed"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/cadastro_prosseguir_btn"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/llRestoCadastro"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/fundocomsombra"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"  >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/llOpcoesCadastro"
                android:visibility="visible">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textCadastroNome"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/size12"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorTextGrayForte"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:text="@string/cadastro_nome"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editCadastroNome"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:hint="Digite seu nome"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textCadastroEstado"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/size12"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorTextGrayForte"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:text="@string/cadastro_estado"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="-3dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="-3dp"
                    android:gravity="top|left">

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinnerCadastroEstado"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:visibility="visible" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvInvisibleEstado"
                        android:layout_width="2dp"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinnerCadastroEstado"
                        android:paddingTop="0dp"
                        android:paddingRight="27dp"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="#8C8C8C"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textCadastroCidade"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/size12"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorTextGrayForte"
                    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:text="@string/cadastro_cidade"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="-3dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="-3dp">

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinnerCadastroCidade"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:visibility="visible" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvInvisibleCidade"
                        android:layout_width="2dp"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinnerCadastroCidade"
                        android:paddingTop="0dp"
                        android:paddingRight="27dp"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="#8C8C8C"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textCadastroEmail"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/size12"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorTextGrayForte"
                    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:text="@string/cadastro_email"
                    android:visibility="visible"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editCadastroEmail"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:hint="Digite seu e-mail"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:visibility="visible"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/llTelefones"/>

         <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
             android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
             android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:paddingBottom="10dp"
             android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
             android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
             android:paddingTop="10dp"
             android:background="@drawable/fundocomsombra"
             android:gravity="center_horizontal"
             android:id="@+id/llTelefoneAdd">

             <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/addTelefone"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                 <LinearLayout
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_weight="8">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_add"
                        android:gravity="left"/>

                 </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Adicionar telefone"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"/>

             </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/fundocomsombra"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"  >

            <!-- label e input -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textCadastroTipoVeiculo"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/size12"
                android:textColor="@color/colorTextGrayForte"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:text="@string/cadastro_tipoveiculo"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-3dp"
                android:gravity="top|left">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinnerCadastroTipoVeiculo"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvInvisibleTipo"
                    android:layout_width="2dp"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinnerCadastroTipoVeiculo"
                    android:paddingTop="0dp"
                    android:paddingRight="27dp"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="#8C8C8C"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textCadastroCarroceria"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/size12"
                android:textColor="@color/colorTextGrayForte"
                android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:text="@string/cadastro_carroceria"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-3dp"
                android:gravity="top|left">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinnerCadastroCarroceria"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvInvisibleCarroceria"
                    android:layout_width="2dp"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinnerCadastroCarroceria"
                    android:paddingTop="0dp"
                    android:paddingRight="27dp"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="#8C8C8C"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textCadastroRastreador"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/size12"
                android:textColor="@color/colorTextGrayForte"
                android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:text="@string/cadastro_rastreador"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-3dp"
                android:gravity="top|left">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinnerCadastroRastreador"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvInvisibleRastreador"
                    android:layout_width="2dp"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinnerCadastroRastreador"
                    android:paddingTop="0dp"
                    android:paddingRight="27dp"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="#8C8C8C"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textCadastroMarca"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/size12"
                android:textColor="@color/colorTextGrayForte"
                android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:text="MARCA"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-3dp"
                android:gravity="top|left">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinnerCadastroMarca"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvInvisibleMarca"
                    android:layout_width="2dp"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinnerCadastroMarca"
                    android:paddingTop="0dp"
                    android:paddingRight="27dp"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="#8C8C8C"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textCadastroSenha1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/size12"
                android:textColor="@color/colorTextGrayForte"
                android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:text="@string/cadastro_senha1"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editCadastroSenha1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:hint="Digite sua senha"
                android:textSize="@dimen/size16"
                android:fontFamily="@string/abc_search_hint" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textCadastroSenha2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/size12"
                android:textColor="@color/colorTextGrayForte"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:text="@string/cadastro_senha2"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editCadastroSenha2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:hint="Repita sua senha"
                android:textSize="@dimen/size16"
                android:fontFamily="@string/abc_search_hint" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/btCadastrar"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editCadastroSenha2"
                android:paddingTop="11dp"
                android:paddingBottom="11dp"
                android:background="@layout/fundoverdepressed"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                android:visibility="visible">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/cadastro_btn"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**UPDATE**

Galera, eu não consegui resolver de maneira eficiente, mas pensei em um jeito que funcionou bem.

Como eu tinha um ScrollView, então eu pensei em colocar um evento no elemento para pegar quando o usuário rolar a tela, sendo assim, se o usuário rola o scroll, então eu seto **null** para todos os setErrors(), então a mensagem de erro some, não causando o problema de sobrepor o **ActionBar**. O ruim, é que só vai aparecer a mensagem novamente, se o usuário tentar submeter o formulário com os campos inválidos novamente.

```
((ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.svGeral)).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            // Pra nao ficar entrando aqui sempre que rolar o scroll
            if (errorEnabled) {

                errorEnabled = false;

                campoNome.setError(null);
                campoEmail.setError(null);
                campoSenha1.setError(null);
                campoSenha2.setError(null);

                // Remove alertas telefones
                for (int et = 0; et < telefones.size(); et++) {

                    telefones.get(et).getEtTelefone().setError(null);
                    telefones.get(et).getTvInvisibleTipoTelefone().setError(null);
                    telefones.get(et).getTvInvisibleOperadoraTelefone().setError(null);

                }

            }

            return false;
        }

    });
```

Se alguém tiver uma forma melhor de resolver esse problema, posta pra gente da uma olhada.

Valeu!

Comment: Poderia colocar seu layout xml? Está usando o `Toolbar`? Em que versão esse erro acontece?

Comment: @Wakim Não estou usando Toolbar não. A versão que estou usando para testes é a 4.0. E sobre o layout, ele não influência nessa questão, pelo fato de não ter nada diferente. Eu pesquisei, e percebi que algumas pessoas também tem esse problema. Atualizei com meu xml.